# how to compress uuid and timeuuid?

Tags: java, php, cassandra, uuid, timeuuid

[**uuid**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or Universally unique identifier and [**timeuuid**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614195/in-cassandra-terminology-what-is-timeuuid) are long 128-bit value.

In Cassandra database and because of its concepts I used **uuid** and **timeuuid** for our entities identifier and now I want to compress **uuid** and **timeuuid** or reduce its size when client (user) can see the id in the URL bar.

For example Twitter also used Cassandra but when you open a Tweet, the Tweet's id is like `10153967535312713` but a simple **uuid** is like `10646334-2c02-11e6-bb4a-7720eb141b83` that is more characters and not user friendly *(of course both IDs are not user friendly :D)*

In different programming languages there are some compression functions, such as [gzcompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) in PHP and [GZIPOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html)  in Java but these functions (classes) will compress data and return in GZIP format which is not allowed to use in URL!

Now just by the way is there any way or function/algorithm to get smaller or compressed version of a uuid or timeuuid?

Comment: UUIDs are extremely unlikely to be compressible -- you can't compress random data, and UUIDs are usually randomized.  (And any shorter random data would have a correspondingly higher likelihood of being not actually unique.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter originally developed [Snowflake](https://blog.twitter.com/2010/announcing-snowflake) a long time ago and I believe that it is this id that Twitter is still using.  There are now [many flake id implementations](http://yellerapp.com/posts/2015-02-09-flake-ids.html) available that can generate a UUID like number instead of a true UUID.  I have used [Flake Java](https://github.com/mumrah/flake-java) in a project of mine.